# Inherited method with different type

Tags: c++, oop

i have something like this

```
class A {  
    virtual void doBla(A *a) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void doBla(B *b) { // do stuff ;};
};
```

and i want to do something like

```
A* a = new B();
B* b = new B();
a->doBla(b);
```

or: all children of A are supposed to have a method doBla which takes a parameter of the type of the child. Hope you get my problem and hope someone can help me or convince me that this is bad style :)

edit: added virtual to the methods

Comment: You need to make doBla virtual in A.

Comment: @Neil: I don't believe that'll help in this case. I think what the OP needs is covariant parameter types, which are apparently not currently supported in C++ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#C.2B.2B).

Comment: @Neil: sorry, forget that... thx

Comment: @Dirk: It isn't **necessarily** bad style; it just depends what your `doBla` methods are supposed to do. If you were trying to implement a kind of `isEqual` method that worked on any pair of objects in a particular class hierarchy, this kind of language feature would be helpful. You could emulate it by having the overridden method still taking `A` as its parameter type, but attempting to `dynamic_cast` it to `B` before using it.

Comment: @Neil: I was thinking about doing it like that but considered it really ugly, but i will try it if there's no better solution. thank you!

Comment: @Dirk I think you mean @David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overload functions across base/child classes, and `doBla` member function of class `A` must be public if you want to call it from outside:

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual void doBla(A *a) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void doBla(A *a) { /*do stuff*/ }
};
```

Edit: Note that the declaration of `doBla` function is similar in A and B classes.

Comment: isn't it automatically public?

Comment: @Dirk: class's member functions are private (default) and struct's member functions are public (default).

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible as it stands - a doesn't have a doBla(B* b) function, so when you try to call it on the a instance the compiler can't guarantee in any way that function actually exists, and it doesn't know how to look it up. That's an error or ten.

What you might be looking for is double dispatch.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void doBla(A* a) { a->doBla_impl(this); }
private:
    virtual void doBla_impl(A* a);
    virtual void doBla_impl(B* b);
    // etc
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void doBla(A* a) { a->doBla_impl(this); }
private:
    virtual void doBla_impl(A* a);
    virtual void doBla_impl(B* b);
    // etc
};
```

The trouble with this is that you have to know all the derived types in the base class, which is not always possible or feasible.